# Free or cheap data source for the current European Options prices?

Tags: options, market-data, european-options

Is there a free or cheap (<15$/month) data source for the **current** (not historical) for European Options?

Something like Yahoo Finance option page, with option chain contract prices. It's ok if it's partially incomplete and slightly outdated.

For European companies like Bayer AG, Siemens, Volkswagen, Daimler etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these companies are listed on the Eurex Exchange.

https://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/products/equ/opt

You can pull in the information for free with a 15 minute delay.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you!